# How to draw common part of two wheels, using CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, chart.js, html5-canvas

It is possible to draw common part of two wheels (like in picture) using javascript and CanvasRenderingContext2D. Ultimately, I would like to manipulate the size of the shape, i.e. the maximum size would be a full circle and the minimum would be a point
[goal is red part of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spNI9.jpg)

I was try draw two CanvasRenderingContext2D.ellipse(...) (doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse) but I don't have idea how to get common part of two ellipses

I'm writing a plugin for chart.js and I have the option to only use these methods from CanvasRenderingContext2D:

```js
interface CanvasPath {
    arc(x: number, y: number, radius: number, startAngle: number, endAngle: number, counterclockwise?: boolean): void;
    arcTo(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number, radius: number): void;
    bezierCurveTo(cp1x: number, cp1y: number, cp2x: number, cp2y: number, x: number, y: number): void;
    closePath(): void;
    ellipse(x: number, y: number, radiusX: number, radiusY: number, rotation: number, startAngle: number, endAngle: number, counterclockwise?: boolean): void;
    lineTo(x: number, y: number): void;
    moveTo(x: number, y: number): void;
    quadraticCurveTo(cpx: number, cpy: number, x: number, y: number): void;
    rect(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number): void;
    roundRect(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number, radii?: number | DOMPointInit | (number | DOMPointInit)[]): void;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marking the intersecting area between two circles in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045224/marking-the-intersecting-area-between-two-circles-in-canvas)

Comment: or [html5 canvas venn 3 circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871723/html5-canvas-venn-3-circles)

Comment: @pilchard links you provided was help me and I solved it this way:
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.ellipse(centerX1, centerY1, radius1, radius1, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.clip('evenodd');
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.ellipse(centerX2, centerY2, radius2, radius2, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.clip('evenodd');
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fill();

thanks

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it helped

Comment: @eKangu Please post that code as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.ellipse(x, y, radius1, radius1, rotation, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        // ctx.stroke();
        ctx.clip('evenodd');

        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(x2, y2, radius2, radius2, rotation, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        // ctx.stroke();
        // ctx.clip('evenodd');

        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.fillStyle = connectToShadowData.color;
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).